# Are any other systems' manpages available on Ubuntu?

Tags: documentation, manpage

The [manpage of `man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/man.1.html) mentions a curious option:

```
-m system[,...], --systems=system[,...]
      If this system has access to  other  operating  system's  manual
      pages,  they can be accessed using this option.  To search for a
      manual page from NewOS's manual page collection, use the  option
      -m NewOS.

      The  system  specified  can  be a combination of comma delimited
      operating system names.  To  include  a  search  of  the  native
      operating  system's manual pages, include the system name man in
      the argument string.  This  option  will  override  the  $SYSTEM
      environment variable.
```

I guess it's referring to [this NewOS](http://newos.org/). However, [a search of the Package Index for `newos`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=newos&searchon=all) came up empty. (Not that I am interested in NewOS - I don't care about it, but I *am* curious as to what I can do with this option.)

Are any other systems' manpages available in Ubuntu? If not, how is this option supposed to be used?

---

We have POSIX manpages available in a separate package, and those manpages have `posix` appended to the section number (`1posix`, etc.). However, `posix` doesn't seem to be a system:

```
$ man -wm posix ls
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

Comment: This feature is discussed briely in `/usr/share/doc/man-db/man-db-manual.txt.gz`, but it seems to be rather obscure.

Comment: @fkraiem Interesting. It says that I have to NFS mount other systems' manpage directories under `/usr/share/man`. That makes the feature rather less useful than I'd hoped. :/

Comment: It says NFS is "the accepted way", not sure what that means exactly but it would be surprising if other ways (*e.g.*, `mount -o bind`, or even just copying files) didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ubuntu placement of man pages with respect to that feature is broken:

- Entering `man -wm es man` shows `/usr/share/man/es/man1/man.1.gz`, that is, the spanish manual page for man(1) as installed by package `man-db`
- Similar to what you noticed about POSIX manpages, `freebsd-manpages` install into their own sections instead of under a distinct "operating system's manual pages" and can be viewed accordingly, for example `man 3freebsd sysctl`

FWIW, the same confusing behaviour of `-m` is present on ArchLinux and Debian. Implementation of `-m` on FreeBSD concerns the machine architecture, not operating system.

To answer your question's title, at least GNU/kFreeBSD manpages are available, but not using the documented method of viewing them.

(As an aside, [initial commit to NewOS repository](http://git.newos.org/?p=newos.git;a=commit;h=9f8ca17c57099eacac49ae707f0cd9ab700d5169) is from 2000, but [initial commit to GNU man-db man(1) source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/diff/man/man1/man.man1?id=190b315e1caed82966c31306213aa58ab62abdf8) shows a copyright from 1995 along with a reference to NewOS, as does the most recent version of man-db in Debian bo. This possibly indicates that NewOS was used as a placeholder name instead of referring to the actual software.)

Comment: `es` working as a system is probably an unintended effect of locales and systems both being implemented as directories in the main directoy.